# Get admin name in blade using bitfumes MultiAuth Laravel package

Tags: laravel

{{Auth::admin()->name}} this gives error, how will i retrieve the current admin name from the database using blade.

I'm getting this error, Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::admin does not exist.

Comment: @dedevsam247 please share error what kind of error is you facing

Comment: I'm getting this error, Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::admin does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This works. `{{ auth('admin')->user()->name }}`